# Understanding why $\int _0^\infty e^{-st}\cos(w t)dt=\frac{e^{-st}}{-s}\Big|_0^\infty-\frac{w}{s}\int _0^\infty e^{-st}\sin(w t)dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

From Advanced Engineering Mathematics, Erwin Kreyszig  chapter 6.1, example 4:

$$\int _0^{\infty}e^{-st}\cos(\omega t)dt=\frac{e^{-st}}{-s} \Big |_0^{\infty}-\frac{\omega}{s}\int _0^{\infty}e^{-st}\sin(\omega t)dt $$

I know that the second term is from integration by parts but what about the first term on the right-hand side?

Comment: What about it? Do you know integration by parts works?

Comment: Hint... $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ now integrate both sides....

Comment: Why is there an evaluation bar from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty h'=h(\infty)-h(0)$

Answer (score 2):

This is a shorthand notation.  First do
$$
\int _0^{M}e^{-st}\cos(\omega t)dt=\frac{e^{-st}}{-s} \;\Bigg |_0^{M}-\frac{\omega}{s}\int _0^{M}e^{-st}\sin(\omega t)dt
$$
then take the limit as $M \to +\infty$.  It uses this evaluation notation:
$$
\frac{e^{-st}}{-s} \;\Bigg |_0^{M} = \frac{e^{-sM}}{-s} - \frac{e^{-s0}}{-s}
$$
so the limit is
$$
\frac{e^{-st}}{-s} \;\Bigg |_0^{\infty} = 
\lim_{M \to \infty}\left(\frac{e^{-sM}}{-s} - \frac{e^{-s0}}{-s}\right)
=\frac{1}{s}
$$
provided $s>0$.

Comment: It doesn't change the result, but you forgot the $\cos(\omega t)$ in the first term...

Comment: @GEdgar I was about to make the same (first portion) of Diger's comment.  However, I am confused as to why it doesn't change the result.  If you evaluate $\frac{e^{-(st)}}{-s} \times \cos(\omega t)$ at M and 0, don't you get a different result than if the $\cos(\omega t)$ factor is omitted?

Comment: $\cos(\omega 0) = 1$, no difference.  $\cos(\omega t)$ is bounded, so the $+\infty$ limit is still $0$.  Anyway: @Diger ... Don't tell me that $\cos$ was forgotten, tell the OP ... or maybe tell Kreyszig if that mistake is actually in the text.

Comment: @GEdgar (and to Diger) Oh, I got it now.  The result is different for $M.$ But at $t = 0$, the cosine factor is 1.  Also, as M goes to infinity (that is as $t \to \infty$), the oscillating (and bounded) cosine factor becomes irrelevant because $e^{-st} \to 0.$

Comment: @GEdgar I think that Diger is suggesting that if you edit your *answer*, including the cosine factor and explaining the calculation, then your answer will be easier for the OP to follow.  Assuming that that is what Diger is suggesting, I agree (case in point : I was temporarily thrown before I made the connection).